# How to use :private-members: and :protected-members: together in doxygen?

Tags: python-sphinx, private, protected, restructuredtext

My aim is to display in concrete class all members: public, protected and private.

I has this rst file:

```
.. _label:

----

MyClass
=======

.. doxygenclass:: MyClass
    :project: MyProject
    :members:
    :private-members:
    :protected-members:
```

But when making html I has this warning:

```
file.rst:6: WARNING: Error in "doxygenclass" directive:
invalid option value: (option: "private-members"; value: ':protected-members:')
no argument is allowed; ":protected-members:" supplied.

.. doxygenclass:: MyClass
    :project: MyProject
    :members:
    :private-members:
        :protected-members:
```

What value I should use for `:private-members:` for solving this problem?

Comment: Doxygen doesn't know about `rst` files, I think this file is only used in a `python sphinx` phase. So not a doxygen problem (though also no doxygen version specified).

Comment: Try removing `:project: MyProject` and `protected-members` because they are not valid options in reStructuredText's autodoc. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html for all valid options. I don't know if Breathe (an extension that bridges Doxygen to Sphinx) extends Sphinx with these options.

Comment: Breathe defines a custom `doxygenclass` directive: https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#doxygenclass. The problem might simply be bad alignment of options in the RST file so that `:protected-members:` is interpreted as the value of `:private-members:`.